# What is an execution model in programming languages?

Tags: compiler-construction, execution

I've been reading Wikipedia article about execution model which said that:

*An execution model specifies how work takes place.Every programming language has an execution model, which is specified as part of language specification and i implemented as part of the language implementation.*

is it something like native implementation of printf ? can anyone please clarify ?

Comment: The Wiki article seems to be making a very wild claim. I don't find anything resembling a specific 'execution model' in for example the COBOL specifications.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple descriptions of different language's execution model that I was able to google up for you.  It's about how the software is built for its eventual execution, not function implementations.

> Java’s program execution model is divided into two distinct stages –
>   Compilation, 
>   Bytecode Execution.
>   These two stages are not directly related to each other. In fact, most of the times the second step occurs on a different machine and usually long after the first step.

http://codingraptor.com/java/compile-run-wora/

> PHP execution model is quite simple actually and follow a cgi-like model. It simply take the php file as it's input, parse and interpret it and then return what ever output the script produced, pass it back to apache as response that will return back to requesting user (browser).

https://blog.xoxzo.com/2012/05/02/php-execution-model-vs-python-web/